# Function seems to be executing non-sequentially when creating an HTML table from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, object, html-table

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but for some reason I can't spot my mistake. The statement at the end of the function seems to be executing prior to the for loop, which I'm sure isn't the case.

```
var object = {
    "key1":"foo",
    "key2":"bar"
}

var message = document.getElementById("message");

message.innerHTML = "<table>";

for(var index in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        message.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + index + "</td><td>" + object[index] + "</td></tr>";
    }
}

message.innerHTML += "</table>";
```

I figured this would create the string:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>key1</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>key2</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

However, when I inspect element, I'm getting this result:

```
<div id="message">
    <table></table> <!-- why would </table> be in the string before key1 etc.? -->
    key1fookey2bar
</div>
```

When I replace the table with line breaks, it looks like the loop is executing correctly, so I'm not sure what's happening. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: not sure why you're seeing that behavior, but I'd recommend building up your string differently - string concatenation is a little expensive - maybe instead push string chunks into an array, then join them all right before setting the innerHTML with it

Comment: Yep, I realize that's the way to go, I'm just curious if there's an explanation for the behaviour when adding straight to innerHTML? I've never had too much problem with that in the past.

Comment: When you append it directly to innerHTML it is trying to actually add it to the DOM right away.

So, when you first call it - you're appending "<table>" without a closing tag. The browser is forgiving, so it closes the table for you. The next time you call innerHTML, you're trying to add tr's and td's - but at this point your table is already closed, and because the browser is forgiving and sees you putting tr's and td's outside of a table - it strips the markup. Finally, you go to close the table (but its already been closed) and so the browser just ignores it.

Comment: If it all possible, I try to avoid building html using string concatenation. You'd be a lot better off using the `document.createElement` method coupled with `appendChild`. Basically, you still let the browser build the HTML but you do it in such a way that you aren't building a monstrous string that is difficult to maintain and follow.

Comment: Interesting! I was actually curious about that so I tested it with IE8 thinking IE8 wouldn't be forgiving enough to do that for me and I'd see the unmatched tags, but I guess it's smarter than I gave it credit for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are appending directly to the innerHTML of the message.

Build your html using a variable, and then set message.innerHTML = that variable.

As in:

```
var messageElement = document.getElementById("message");
var message = "<table>";

for(var index in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        message += "<tr><td>" + index + "</td><td>" + object[index] + "</td></tr>";
    }
}

message += "</table>";
messageElement.innerHTML = message;
```